# Any Angular library to directly query on json?

Tags: json, angularjs

I am building an angular app with a rest endpoint as back-end. I already have my data in a json file and my data is almost static and not that big.  Is it possible to let angular directly query on this JSON file, instead of relying on the remote rest endpoint?

**Solution:**

I have used [linqjs](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) for my purpose and it works great. Thanks.

Comment: When you sayu 'query on this JSON file' do you mean retrieve the file?  Or do you mean manipulate the data, perhaps by filtering it or performing other operations? You could use a JavaScript filter ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter ) to create a new array which is a subset of your existing array.  There is also a JavaScript library for Linq ( http://linqjs.codeplex.com/ ) which will allow you to perform Linq operations on the array.  It is like Linq, the SQL-ish library used by Microsoft.

Comment: I mean manipulating data. Thanks for the linqjs pointer. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can query it directly using `$http.get` or an equivalent call. It works the same as any other `$http` call, except you obviously can't post, put, or delete.

```
 $http.get('mydata.json')
      .success(function(data) {
         $scope.mydata = data;
        });
```

Comment: I can get the json, but can I do queries on it? I want to do queries like, get me all data that contain a particular tag... I came across some json query libraries like jsonpath (http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/). Can I use them from within angular?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, you could use a third-party script. You can also use `$filter` if it's simple enough of a query.

Comment: To be clear, once you have retrieved the data in `success`, you can refer to your third-party utility to do the query from there.

Comment: Thanks a tonne, HackedByChinese (cool handle, btw). Lemme try doing that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the script you linked, but the examples have `$.` in them which is making me think it's based on jQuery. If so, just make sure to include jQuery before you include Angular. Other than that, just follow their directions.